# What's wrong with the following program ? it runs infinitely

Tags: python-2.7

```
from skimage.measure import structural_similarity as ssim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

img_counter=0
flag=False

def mse(imageA, imageB):
    # the 'Mean Squared Error' between the two images is the

    err = np.sum((imageA.astype("float") - imageB.astype("float")) ** 2)
    err /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])


    return err

def compare_images(imageA, imageB):
    # compute the mean squared error and structural similarity
    # index for the images
    m = mse(imageA, imageB)
    s = ssim(imageA, imageB)

    if m > 150 or s < 0.90:
        print "object is detected"
        flag=True

while True:

    original = cv2.imread("/home/lingesh/last_try/images/0.jpg")
    shopped = cv2.imread("/home/lingesh/last_try/images/{}.jpg".format(img_counter+1))
    # convert the images to grayscale
    original = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    shopped = cv2.cvtColor(shopped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    compare_images(original, shopped)
    if flag==True
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in `compare_images` you think that it will modify your global variable `flag` but that is not the case, when you do `flag=True` inside it you really a creating a new variable with the same name inside it, use a return instead

```
def compare_images(imageA, imageB):
    # compute the mean squared error and structural similarity
    # index for the images
    m = mse(imageA, imageB)
    s = ssim(imageA, imageB)

    if m > 150 or s < 0.90:
        print "object is detected"
        return True
    return False
```

and in the loop

```
while True:
    #code
    if compare_images(original, shopped):
        break
```

or if you need the flag thing later on do

```
while True:
    #code
    flag = compare_images(original, shopped)
    if flag:
        break
```

also it look like you don't modify `img_counter` or `original` or `shopped` or anything else so you forever will doing the same thing over and over again if they compare different